# Why AsyncTask doesn't show result first time?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a text file on a server (right now on a local server by WAMP in c:/wamp/www/android/sample.txt ) and an android application with 3 activity that read data through the WiFi.
The first one get the address (on local host use 10.0.2.2/android/sample.txt) and go to activity2. In activity2 I have a button that goes to activity3.

code is third activity:

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws Exception {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
        throw new IOException("NOT an HTTP Connection!");
    }
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpCon.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpCon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpCon.connect();
        response = httpCon.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpCon.getInputStream();
            Log.d("myerr", response + "");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("myerr2", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new IOException("Error Connection!");
    }
    return in;
}

private String DownloadText(String URL) {
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("myerr", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return "";
    }
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
    int charRead;
    String str = "";
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try {
        while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
            String readString = String
                    .copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
            str += readString;
            inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("myerr", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return "";
    }
    return str;
}

private  class DownloadTextTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected  String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return DownloadText(urls[0]);
    }

    protected  void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Global.readedDataFromFile=result;
        //Toast.makeText(DrawRhActivity.this,"Result: "+Global.readedDataFromFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw_rh);

    String user_address = Global.ip_address;
    new DownloadTextTask().execute(user_address);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("Value: " + Global.readedDataFromFile);

}
```

I also define some global variable in Global.java .
AND HERE IS MY PROBLEM:
The 3rd activity doesn't show data on textview at the first time. but when I back to 2nd activity and hit the button my data loaded. 
Why AsyncTask doesn't show result first time and how to fix this?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: post your code for activty  as per your code the error may be you are reading text from Global.readedDataFromFile and when async task postexecute called you are not setting text

Comment: try to load data in postExecute

Answer (score 1):

```
tv.setText("Value: " + Global.readedDataFromFile);
```

write this line in onPostExecute

```
protected  void onPostExecute(String result) {

    Global.readedDataFromFile=result;
    //Toast.makeText(DrawRhActivity.this,"Result: "+Global.readedDataFromFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
tv.setText("Value: " + Global.readedDataFromFile);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

put `tv.setText("Value: " + Global.readedDataFromFile);` in your `onPostExecute` method.

**Explaination:**

`AsyncTask` runs on separate thread instead of your UI thread.
so when it is being executed `Global.readedDataFromFile` may be empty.and when execution completes it goes in `onPostExecute` method and now `Global.readedDataFromFile` have some value stored in it.

**Issue:**
you are setting the text instantly after calling `new DownloadTextTask().execute(user_address);`
so it may happen that the `AsyncTask` is not completed yet and `Global.readedDataFromFile` is empty.

**Reference:**
[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

I hope it will be helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies within your `onCreate` function:

```
String user_address = Global.ip_address;
new DownloadTextTask().execute(user_address);

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("Value: " + Global.readedDataFromFile);
```

First you start a task, then you want to set your views, but your task is not finished.
You have to set the views with the result of your task in to `onPostExecute` of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your DownloadTextTask &
Trying this code in your Activity

```
DownloadTextTask textTask = new DownloadTextTask();
textTask.execute(user_address);
String strDownloaded = "";
try {
    strDownloaded = textTask.get();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("DownloadTextTask", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```